# get two totals in one sql query

Tags: mysql, sql

How can I get the total of `hectar` and total `amount` in one row rather than looping it in many rows with php and mysql?

I am using the following sql table:

-- Database: `officedb`

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `agricollectcropedata` (
  `kebele` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `croptype` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  `hektar` int(40) NOT NULL,
  `amount` int(20) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;


INSERT INTO `agricollectcropedata` (`kebele`, `croptype`, `hektar`, `amount`) VALUES
('b', 'wheet', 2, 12),
('a', 'wheet', 1, 5),
('a', 'wheet', 2, 6),
('a', 'wheet', 3, 12),
('a', 'wheet', 0, 0),
('a', 'wheet', 0, 0);
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with PHP or fetch. I've re-tagged it for you. Also, your title should be a summary of the problem, not the entire content of your question. I've edited it. For future reference, please take the [tour] and read [ask] before posting again. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT 
  sum(hektar) as hektar, 
  sum(amount) as amount 
FROM 
  agricollectcropedata
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thank you! This query only  display one row for one croptype from the table. if the crop type is different and when we apply it in while loop  the duplicate row will occur. How to solve that?

Comment: Last Query Add ---> "Group By kebele"